# Problems in using GRUB2 - Manjaro

Tags: linux, grub2, grub, manjaro

I hope you are well!

I use Manjaro x64_86, using GRUB2 and EFI.

I made a large error after coming home from a night shift. I accidentally removed my boot partition when attempting to format an external hard drive for my girlfriend. I followed instructions [from the Manjaro wiki to reinstall grub.](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader)

Some steps are confusing, specifically at the start it asks you to mount your boot partition to /mnt/boot:

`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot`

Then later in the EFI section, it asks you to mount the boot partition to /boot/efi:

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi`

I wonder if this has contributed.

I happily updated grub using update-grub, without any major hitches:

`sudo update-grub`

Unfortunately whenever I need to update grub, it does not work. It appears that my computer is using /boot/efi/grub/grub.cfg rather than the /boot/grub/grub.cfg that is automatically updated when I update my kernel/run the update-grub command from inside my currently running Manjaro install.

I have attempted to read through various wikis about GRUB2 and EFI, but each one is asking me to read more and more information. Is there any chance I can change this so it updates automatically again? I promise I'll never use gparted when I'm tired again! :)

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Specifically my problem now is that when I use sudo update-grub, it only changes

`/boot/efi/grub/grub.cfg`

and when I turn on my pc and grub loads, it appears to be using

`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

instead, which isn't being updated.

Comment: Between your `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot` and the `mount /dev/sda1/boot/efi` is the requirement to `chroot` (this temporarily moves the top of your directory hierarchy (i.e. `/`) to the `/mnt` directory). You didn't mention this vital step; did you miss it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it, but I religiously followed the steps.

My problem now is that when I use sudo update-grub, it only changes /boot/efi/grub/grub.conf and when I turn on my pc and grub loads, it appears to be using /boot/grub/grub.conf instead, which isn't being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some more reading and I have found the way to update my grub.conf in a different directory. I have not checked if this will now allow it to update automatically in the future, but at least I have a working solution.

My problem was GRUB2 was using

`/boot/efi/grub/grub.cfg`

and running the script

`update-grub`

was only updating

`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

So I simply ran:

`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/grub/grub.cfg`

and GRUB2 now loads the additional kernels I had installed.

However, I have not made this work automatically. I think I will see if it is functioning later, if it is not, I will sym-link

`/boot/efi/grub/`

to

`/boot/grub`

I have not tested this further solution, so caution is advised.